# Easy about Angular: Why does it change order?

Tags: angularjs, variables, printing, console, long-integer

Just a 'silly' question but it's confusing me a lot, for a student of AngularJS.

When console.logging a variable, let's say `var result` is a promise from a GET or whatever, and `.then()` I do some tasks, like asignin a variable.

```
    var result = ... ;

    $scope.number = {};


    result.then(function(data) {
        $scope.number = 5;

        console.log($scope.number);
    });


console.log($scope.number);
```

Okay!
So to me, this  should print

```
5
5
```

(In case I initialise a $scope variable, outside this function or promise)

```
5
undefined
```

(in case the second .log tries to print a non-defined global variable, outside the function)

So I get:

```
undefined
5
```

Why does the outter `$scope.number` print before the inner (5) variable?

I want to initialise the variable after getting the `GET`, within the promise, and later on, use the initialised var.

Thank you =) This will speed up my learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing to understand is that the following returns a promise immediately:

```
var result = ... ;
```

Right after that, you pass a function to the `.then` method of the promise:

```
result.then(...)
```

And right after that you do:

```
console.log($scope.number);
```

Then later - once the asynchronous action (like an HTTP request) completes and the promise resolves - the function you passed to `.then` finally executes:

```
function(data) {
    $scope.number = 5;

    console.log($scope.number);
}
```

So promises exist to help you manage asynchronous behavior. They really start to shine when you have to manage multiple asychronous functions:

```
asyncFunction1().then(function() {
    // This executes after asyncFunction1 completes
    return asyncFunction2();
}).then(function() {
    // This executes after asyncFunction2 completes
});
```

Comment: Great, I understand it better now.
I will see it 'similarly' to Recursive Functions, that the parent function keeps waiting till its child function finishes.

So if I want to keep working with $scope.number, let's say it is a number that returns with a HTTP.GET, I should concatenate with another function?
For example, like you did? 

`asyncFunction1().then(function(data) {
    $scope.number = data;
    return asyncFunction2($scope.number);
}).then(function() {
    console.log($scope.number);
});`
Again, its an easy code, 1st initialises number, and second, can process it.

Comment: Any other way to process the $scope.variable within the promise, to process it later consecuently? Thank you!

Comment: The way you are doing it looks correct. You are setting $scope.number inside of the function you passed to `.then`, thus you are waiting for the http response to finish. You only need a second function if you return another promise from the first function, like if you had to make a second http request after the first completed.

Comment: Alright! I think I wanted to use a Promise like a Function. Use it, get something done, and carry on. Promises work in a different way. Thank you @fmodica! =D